# Extract Categories and Create a new Category in Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, categories, win32com

I like to check the existing categories in outlook and create a new one (with a customized name and assign a color to that) if it does not exist.

For example, Category "Spam" with color Red.

I am using Python and win32com package.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are stored in a hidden message with the message class of `"IPM.Configuration.CategoryList"` in the store's Calendar folder. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you go to the shared Calendar folder and click the IMAPIFolder button, then go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

That hidden message can be accessed using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` in the Outlook Object Model.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can also access the categories using [RDOCategories](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocategories.htm) collection. Redemption exposes  categories both on the session level ([RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Categories` from the default store) and on the store level ([RDOStore2](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOStore2).`Categories`).

In VBA:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT 'if you are already working with OOM
set Categories = Session.Categories
set Category = Categories.Add("Test Category", olCategoryColorPeach)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to do it in Python?